# Update S3 bucket without deleting it

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation

I've got an S3 bucket with a bunch of files in it - I don't want to disturb those files if possible. However, I do need to update a policy on the S3 bucket. We're doing everything through Cloudformation, and I'm running into an issue where I cannot seem to update the bucket without deleting it first.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-attribute-deletionpolicy.html
I've read this page, but I don't think any of those options do what I need.

Comment: Just update the policy that is all I think.

Comment: If it's a Cloud formation stack, best practice is to update the stack via the template. What error message do you get when you update it?

Comment: Can you post the template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[S3 Bucket Policies](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-s3-policy.html) are a different resource in cloudformation from the actual bucket.

Changing the Policy Document attribute on the policy requires "no interruption" which is generally the type of update that you want.

Since you mentioned an error while trying to perform the update, my guess is something else is actually causing the error since the policy change alone wouldn't do it.

Can you please post the error message you're receiving?

Comment: So the issue is basically that in my organization, there's a level of opaqueness between the CFT that I write and what actually goes into cloudformation. Based on the comments above I figured out I just needed to get THAT layer of code to perform an update. I'm accepting your answer though because putting the policies in a separate stack would also solve the problem, and maybe could even be preferable in some scenarios. Thanks!